# editText inside an Expandable List view creating issue

Tags: expandablelistview

I am having a problem that I have edittext and spinner inside an expandableListView and after writing something in editText when I hide the soft keyboard my expandablelistView gets recycled to its previous state and all the values which i changed gets Lost.

The main problem with my code is that my view is getting generated through an xml page which is being made in server and so i cannot tell that whether an editText going to come or not.

I am retaining value using hashMap and its getting retain in expand and collapse but the only problem I am facing is that whenever soft input keyboard is opened and then closed my expandable gets recycled.

I think if in my adapter I can know about the soft input keyboard status like it is shown or hidden then I may retain the status of it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to preserve the state of the `EditText` in the adapter. for example, add a change listener and write it to a model object/DAO. you should read it from your model in the `onCreateView()`.

if you don't know what elements are comming it will get hard to store all information. you could search the tree for `EditText.class.equals(view.getClass())` and save the state in a map maybe using the id from your data model or items of the adapter.

you should not care about keyboard presence if you do all things right